# SQL: Finding the Minimum aggregate using only count

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, sql-order-by

I'm using DB2 for a project and looking to find which Group has the fewest members without using the **min** feature. My idea is to find all the groups and then subtract out any group which has more members from some other group thus leaving me with the group with that has no more members than any other group, i.e. the min.

So far I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.group as Group, count(P.id) as Count
FROM People P
EXCEPT
SELECT P.group, count(P.id) 
FROM People P, People O
WHERE count(P.cid) > count(O.cid);
```

With a schema for People like

```
create table People (
    group  varchar(25)  not null,
    id   smallint     not null,
);
```

I am getting the following error:

> SQL0119N  An expression starting with "CLUB" specified in a SELECT clause, 
>   HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or 
>   it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column 
>   function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.  SQLSTATE=42803

If you could help point out what I am doing wrong or the correct format for such a query it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find which Group has the fewest members

You can aggregate by group, order by member count, and fetch the top row only:

```
select p.group as grp, count(*) as cnt
from people p
group by p.group
order by count(*)
fetch first 1 rows only
```

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed probably a better way :) I was just wondering how I would be able to use the EXCEPT feature with this type of query?

Comment: @baed: mm, `EXCEPT` does not look like a good fit for this task. The key thing is order by/fetch first - except can't help with that.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I was eventually able to get it working with except but it is quite bloated lol : `WITH
  first (Club, Count) as 
(SELECT M.club, count(M.cid)
FROM Member as M
GROUP BY M.club),
  second (Club, Count) as
(SELECT M.club, count(M.cid)
FROM Member as M
GROUP BY M.club)

SELECT F.club as Club, F.count as Count
FROM First F
EXCEPT
SELECT F.club, F.count
FROM first F, second S
WHERE F.count > S.count;`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use min(). Very straight forward. From your Error message, it seems like your HAVING clause is wrong so it would look into that.